# Assign JavaScript variable value from view to controller variable

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to assign a value from a variable created in JavaScript in my view to a variable in my controller. How can I do that? I am new to CodeIgniter and JavaScript.

The idea is that I validate an email input field in my view with JavaScript and then assign that value to a controller variable and then retrieve that value in my controller.

`$john_email` is my controller variable and `email` my JavaScript variable

```
$('#submitRequests').click(function(){
console.log("Clicked submit");
var data = getTableContent();
console.log("machines: ");
console.log(data);
var email = $("#emailInput").val();
if(isEmail(email)){
    $john_email = email; // something like this!
    uploadMachines(data);
}
else 
    alert("Incorrect email");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're very new to client-server programming. JavaScript runs on the client (web browser), PHP runs on the server. To send data from JavaScript to PHP, you need to submit the data back to the server, either by posting the page, or by using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) for asynchronous communication with the server (allowing you to send data back to the server and update the page on the client without posting and reloading it).
There are many great tutorials on AJAX out there, and I've linked, what I feel, is the best one. Read up on the subject, and if you still need help, report back with what code you've tried and what results you got.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery in your code, take a look of jQuery.ajax() method. Also, for CodeIgniter take a look of Input class.

Answer (score 0):

// Javascript

```js
 $('#submitRequests').click(function(){
     console.log("Clicked submit");
     var data = getTableContent();
     console.log("machines: ");
     console.log(data);
     var email = $("#emailInput").val();
     if(isEmail(email)){             
          $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: base_url + "controller/post_email", //here base_url = http://domain.com
                   data: {email: email},
                   dataType: "text",  
                   cache:false,
                   success: 
                        function(john_email){
                         alert(john_email);                          
                        }

               return false;
           });
     }
     else 
         alert("Incorrect email");
     });
```

//codeigniter controller

```html
<?php
     function post_email()
     {   
        $john_email = $_POST['email'];

        return $john_email;
     }
?>
```